# Why I had lost my reputation while I do nothing and no one was removed?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation now is $1.083$ but i remember that in a several day ago my reputation is about $1.1\text{k}$[image]

I didn't downvote any answers and i didn't receive any notification about someone downvote my answer, question or user was removed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're being shown ***removed posts***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your reputation still displays as 1.1k if you go to [your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/466835/word-shallow?tab=profile) and look under "Communities", which appears to be where you got your original screenshot.  So all that's going on is that the site rounds 1,083 to 1.1k when displaying your reputation in certain contexts.

(The only such context I can find at the moment is in fact the "Communities" list on the profile page; in most contexts [reputation scores are not rounded or otherwise abbreviated unless they are at least 10,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217197/how-is-the-reputation-value-formatted-when-it-gets-abbreviated).)